# MangoDB using JavaScript Pattern with $in operator

Tags: javascript, python, design-patterns, pymongo

Trying to create a MongoDB query with the Pymongo driver that search a database for some dog breeds, but I need to do pattern matching due to data being of differing quality. I know I cannot use Regex in a $in style query so I am using JS patterns.

I have this so far:

```
df = shelter.getRecords({
    "breed": {"$in": [/labrador/i, /chesa/i, /newfound/i]}
    })
```

But I get syntax errors. Command seems to work in Mongo shell....is this a limitation of Pymongo?

Comment: Have you tried using `pymongo`'s [`bson.regex.Regex`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/bson/regex.html#bson.regex.Regex)?

Comment: I did try than and came up with a hybrid approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *could* use `"$regex"` like this.

N.B.: Your `pymongo` query filter could be  a `python` dictionary like `{'breed': {'$regex': '(labrador)|(chesa)|(newfound)', '$options': 'i'}}`.

```js
db.shelter.find({
  "breed": {
    "$regex": "(labrador)|(chesa)|(newfound)",
    "$options": "i"
  }
})
```

Example output:

```json
[
  {
    "_id": 21,
    "breed": "Chesapeake Retriever"
  },
  {
    "_id": 80,
    "breed": "Newfoundland"
  }
]
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lA9EoAYi77R).

Comment: Thanks I used a very similar approach!

Answer (score 0):

In the end this was my hybrid approach...

```
           labRegex = re.compile(".*lab.*", re.IGNORECASE)
           chesaRegex = re.compile(".*chesa.*", re.IGNORECASE)
           newRegex = re.compile(".*newf.*", re.IGNORECASE)
           
           df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(shelter.getRecordCriteria({
               '$or':[ #Regex isn't allowed in an $in helper so use $or
                   {"breed": {'$regex': newRegex}}, #pass the regex to the filter
                   {"breed": {'$regex': chesaRegex}},
                   {"breed": {'$regex': labRegex}},
               ],
               "sex_upon_outcome": "Intact Female",
               "age_upon_outcome_in_weeks\": {"$gte":26.0, "$lte":156.0}
           }))
```